# php explode on two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a two dimensional array in php and I want to get the second dimension (index 1) as a list of values seperated by a comma.
Do I have to write my own custom functions or can I use some variation of explode on two dimensional arrays?

Comment: I've changed your tags: Added 'php' and 'array' tags. And not sure what your question had to do with MySQL, so removed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your are looking for [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) and not for [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode).

```
function flatten($two_dim_array)
{
     $result = array();
     foreach ($two_dim_array as $array)
          $result[] = implode("," $array);
     return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how your array is organized, you could do

```
x = implode(',',$two_dimensional_array['index1']);
```